# Interpretation of Android phonecall types

Tags: android, phone-call, android-phone-call

The Android call logs give a type to each call, one of seven options: `BLOCKED_TYPE`, `INCOMING_TYPE`, `MISSED_TYPE`, `OUTGOING_TYPE`, `REJECTED_TYPE`, `VOICEMAIL_TYPE`, and `ANSWERED_EXTERNALLY_TYPE`.

My application is scanning through call logs, but I'm having difficulty interpreting this type information. The trouble is the options don't seem to be disjoint, i.e. a call I make that is rejected on the other end is both `OUTGOING_TYPE` and `REJECTED_TYPE`. A call that is incoming that I reject is `INCOMING_TYPE` and `REJECTED_TYPE`.

So it seems I'm missing something, and [the docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/CallLog.Calls.html) themselves don't seem sufficient to make a proper interpretation.

My best guess is that `BLOCKED_TYPE`, `MISSED_TYPE`, `REJECTED_TYPE`, `VOICEMAIL_TYPE`, and `ANSWERED_EXTERNALLY_TYPE` all imply `INCOMING_TYPE`, and everything else is simply an unadorned `OUTGOING_TYPE` call. This is based on the assumption that the phone system does not provide meta-information on how the recipient of my call handled it, thus all the extra information about handling is coming from my phone itself and is about my actions, not theirs.

But I don't really know that. This is a very new area for me. Can someone please enlighten me as to what these call types really mean?

Comment: WHy not test yourself?  Call your phone from some other device (skype if you have to). Reject the call.  See if it adds to the log as rejected or incoming.  Call someone else from your device.  Have them reject it.  See what it comes into your log as.